# URI Routing for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how I should do this. The following controller is for a bio page for each wrestler. Here's an example.

http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/bio/kid-wonder

Now if you notice there's three links Biography, Wrestling, Appearances.

One question I have is should all three be different functions inside this controller?

If the answer is yes are the links actually correct on the page link?

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Bio extends CI_Controller
{

function index($character = "jfkdlsjl")
{

    //Config Defaults Start
    $msgBoxMsgs = array();//msgType = dl, info, warn, note, msg
    $cssPageAddons = '';//If you have extra CSS for this view append it here
    $jsPageAddons = '';//If you have extra JS for this view append it here
    $metaAddons = '';//Sometimes there is a need for additional Meta Data such in the case of Facebook addon's
    $siteTitle = '';//alter only if you need something other than the default for this view.
    //Config Defaults Start


    //examples of how to use the message box system (css not included).
    //$msgBoxMsgs[] = array('msgType' => 'dl', 'theMsg' => 'This is a Blank Message Box...');

    /**********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, Start*/


    $activeTemplate = $this->sitemodel->getTemplate();
    $footerLinks = $this->sitemodel->getFooterNav();
    $bodyContent = "bio";//which view file
    $bodyType = "main";//type of template
    $this->data['activeTemplate'] = $activeTemplate;
    $this->data['footerLinks']= $footerLinks;
    $this->load->model('biomodel');
    if($character !== "jfkdlsjl")
    {
        if((!empty($character))||(!isset($character))||(trim($character) !== '')||($character !== NULL))
        {
            $bioArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterBio($character);
            if ($bioArray == "empty")
            {
                $this->data['bioArray']= array();
            }
            else
            {
                if (($bioArray[0]->characters_statuses_id == 2)||($bioArray[0]->characters_statuses_id == 3)||($bioArray[0]->characters_statuses_id == 5))
                {
                    $this->data['bioArray']= array(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->data['bioArray']= $bioArray;
                    $bioPagesArray = $this->biomodel->getBioPages();
                    $alliesArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterAllies($bioArray[0]->id);
                    $rivalsArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterRivals($bioArray[0]->id);
                    $quotesArray = $this->biomodel->getCharacterQuotes($bioArray[0]->id);
                    $this->data['bioPagesArray']= $bioPagesArray;
                    $this->data['alliesArray']= $alliesArray;
                    $this->data['rivalsArray']= $rivalsArray;
                    $this->data['quotesArray']= $quotesArray;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /***********************************************************Your Coding Logic Here, End*/

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, Start.
    //If msgBoxMsgs array has anything in it, if so displays it in view, else does nothing.
    if(count($msgBoxMsgs) !== 0)
    {
        $msgBoxes = $this->msgboxes->buildMsgBoxesOutput(array('display' => 'show', 'msgs' =>$msgBoxMsgs));
    }
    else
    {
        $msgBoxes = array('display' => 'none');
    }

    if($siteTitle == '')
    {
        $siteTitle = $this->metatags->SiteTitle(); //reads
    }

    //Double checks if any default variables have been changed, End.

    $this->data['msgBoxes'] = $msgBoxes;
    $this->data['cssPageAddons'] = $cssPageAddons;//if there is any additional CSS to add from above Variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['jsPageAddons'] = $jsPageAddons;//if there is any addictional JS to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['metaAddons'] = $metaAddons;//if there is any addictional meta data to add from the above variable this will send it to the view.
    $this->data['pageMetaTags'] = $this->metatags->MetaTags();//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['siteTitle'] = $siteTitle;//defaults can be changed via models/metatags.php
    $this->data['bodyType'] = $bodyType;
    $this->data['bodyContent'] = $bodyContent;
    $this->load->view($activeTemplate[0]->short_name.'/index', $this->data);

}
}

/* End of file bio.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/bio.php */
```

EDIT: I'm really concerned with the biography page link when I'm on the bio page like the link above.

Here's what I have currently for my route: $route['bio/(:any)'] = "bio/index/$1";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the best to have separate controllers for each of the 3 links.

But if you don't want to, and still want the links `/appearances/whatever`, here's the routing you need to keep it all within the Bio controller:

<strike>UPDATE - this is still a bad approach, but it should do.</strike>

```
if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'bio') {
    $route['bio/(:any)'] = "bio/index/$1";
} else {
    $route['wrestling/(:any)'] = "bio/wrestling/$1";
    $route['appearances/(:any)'] = "bio/appearances/$1";
}
```

UPDATE 2: you got me confused, but the first solution HAS to work, even the order doesn't matter:

```
$route['bio/(:any)'] = "bio/index/$1";
$route['wrestling/(:any)'] = "bio/wrestling/$1";
$route['appearances/(:any)'] = "bio/appearances/$1";
```

> `bio/kid` goes to `bio/index/kid`
>
> `wrestling/kid` goes to `bio/wrestling/kid`
>
> `appearances/kid` goes to `bio/appearances/kid`

Comment: but what about the biography link though. It is wanting to go to bio/biography/kid-wonder. It should be going to that index function.

Comment: Adding the one you already have (`$route['bio/(:any)'] = "bio/index/$1";`) below these two should do it.

Comment: Why is it important to place it BELOW the other two? But that didn't work btw.

Comment: I thought it would ignore the other routes once it gets triggered by one of the above. I added a simple if-clause to my answer. This is not an elegant solution and again, it would be the best to use separate controllers or modify the site structure a bit.

Comment: Let me know we you update the code so I can take a look. Btw. I shouldn't be asking this but you do have the other two methods in the Bio controller, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5248/discussion-between-jeff-davidson-and-shomz)

Comment: Talk to me about this if you can in the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have this setup:

**The functions**

```
function index($wrestlerName = null){ }
function wrestling($wrestlerName = null){ }
function appearances($wrestlerName = null){ }
```

**The links**

```
bio/kid-wonder
bio/wrestling/kid-wonder
bio/appearances/kid-wonder
```

If you wanted to have the `wrestling/kid-wonder` and `appearances/kid-wonder` without the bio at the beginning of the url, you are going to need to create new controllers for wrestling and appearances.

```
class wrestler extends CI_Controller {
 function index($wrestlerId = NULL){
   if($wrestlerId != NULL){

   }
 }
}

class appearances extends CI_Controller {
 function index($wrestlerId = NULL){
   if($wrestlerId != NULL){

   }
 }
}
```

Comment: The only change is for the biography link if you notice it goes to bio/biography/kid-wonder instead of bio/kid-wonder which is what it should be going to since its the index function.